# Are android SQLite queries executed lazily?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, lazy-evaluation, android-cursor

I just encountered something strange. Say I have a table

```
_id | caption
 1  | foo
```

and I execute the following query on it directly in SQLite:

```
select _id, (caption != "bar") as caption from the_table;
```

I get the (expected) output:

```
_id | caption
 1  | 1
```

Executing this code however:

```
// This will execute the EXACT SAME query (checked via debugger)
Cursor affected = db.query(table, (String[]) projection.toArray(new String[0]), selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null); 
// ############ UPDATE ROW 1 TO CAPTION=bar #######
int result = db.update(table, values, selection, selectionArgs);

affected.moveToPosition(-1);        
while (affected.moveToNext()) {
    long id = affected.getLong(0); // We made the _id column the first in the projection
    for (int i = 1; i < affected.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        Log.d("xyz", affected.getInt(i) + "");
    }
}
```

gets me: "xyz 0" in LogCat.

**Does the cursor execute the query lazily on the first cursor access?**

It seems to work if I insert `affected.getCount()` right after the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are leaky abstractions.

Query alone translates to a [prepare](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) call that compiles the SQL to a sqlite program (think bytecode). The program is not run.

To run a compiled sqlite program, one would use the [step](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) which either returns a result row, finihsed status code, or an error. In Android, you effectively run the program by calling one of the `moveTo...()` methods on the returned cursor.

Getting cursor count is not directly supported by the sqlite C API. Android [implements](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java#131) it by running the query and storing the results in a "cursor window" buffer. The same buffer is used for accessing the cursor's data later.

Comment: I see. And here I thought for a while I was just going crazy... I will change my `getCount()` to `moveToPosition(-1)` then. What I find shocking is that the Android developer docs don't mention this at all.

Comment: That's the nature of leaky abstractions: to understand higher level behavior you need to know details of the underlying layers. It's not by design (rather it's by accident) and hence not documented.

Comment: That's my point - it should be. But thanks for helping me out here, I'll keep that in mind when dealing with SQLite in the future. :)